# How to deal with different mean response values between training and test sets

Tags: cross-validation

I am currently working on a binary classification Kaggle competition where there is a labeled training set and an unlabeled test set provided, and the objective is to maximize the AUC on the unlabeled test set.  The training set exhibits class imbalance, with roughly 5% of all examples being positive.  I am using stratified 10 fold cross-validation, but am seeing a very large discrepancy between my cross-validated AUC on the training set vs. the AUC on the unlabeled test set (you submit your predictions, and they provide the AUC, without them revealing the correct labels).  I have noticed that the distribution of predictions I make over the test set is overall higher than the predictions I make over the training set.  This suggests to me that the test set potentially has a higher mean response value than the training set.  Under this assumption, I think that stratified cross-validation is not a correct approach for this problem.  What would be a better cross-validation approach, given this observation?